# BoundingBox way of display information

Tags: matlab

What it is the order from the information it is displayed using BoundinBox, I mean is: `{y,x,Δy,Δx}` or`{x,y,Δx,Δy}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on [`regionprops`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) states, that `'BoundingBox'`:

> Returns the smallest rectangle containing the region, (...) for example, `[ul_corner width]`.
>   `ul_corner` specifies the upper-left corner of the bounding box in the form `[x y z ...]`.
>   `width` specifies the width of the bounding box along each dimension in the form `[x_width y_width ...]`.  (...)

So the BoundingBox of an image has the form `[x, y, Δx, Δy]`. Now, the important thing to remember here, is how matrices are indexed in MATLAB. For example:

```
>> x = [1, 2; 3, 4]
x =
     1     2
     3     4

>> x(1:2, 1)
ans =
     1
     3

>> x(1, 1:2)
ans =
     1     2
```

As you can see clearly from this example, MATLAB uses a column-first indexing, i.e. the first dimension in a matrix is the column (*the y-axis*) and the second dimension is the row (*the x-axis*)!

To extract a part of an image using the BoundingBox, you need to remember to do this correctly:

```
>> a = imread('circlesBrightDark.png');
>> bw = a < 100;
>> props = regionprops(bw,'BoundingBox');

>> bbox = props(2).BoundingBox
bbox =
  259.5000   79.5000   81.0000   81.0000

>> x = bbox(1);
>> y = bbox(2);
>> dx = bbox(3);
>> dy = bbox(4);

>> circle = a( y : y+dy , x : x+dx )
```

[image: bw]
[image: result]

```
          bw                        circle
```